# Symfony API : test if the content has the keys

Tags: symfony

With Symfony, I can get the content of request (`POST` and `application/json`) with :

```
$content = json_decode($request->getContent());
```

`dd($content)` return :

```
[
    "subject" => "test"
    "content" => "content"
]
```

I just want to hydrate an object with the subject, this works **good** :

```
$subject = new SubjectEntity();
$subject->setSubject($content['subject]);
```

But I don't want to do a `setSubject()` if the subject key doesn't exist.

I know I can do an `if` for each variable (Or `$subject->setSubject($content['subject] ?? null)`), but I think it will be a bit tedious in more complex cases.

Is there a way to "validate" the content sent to verify that all the desired keys are present ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest solution would be a request param validator using [symfony validator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html)

Example:

```
public function validateRequest(array $params): array
{
    $validator = Validation::createValidator();

    $constraints = new Assert\Collection([
        'subject' => new Assert\Type('string'),
        'content' => new Assert\Type('string'),
    ]);

    $group = new Assert\GroupSequence(['Default', 'custom']);
    return $validator->validate($params, $constraints, );
}
```

If the keys can be optional, then you must use `Assert\Optional()`. Either way, you will need the null coalescing operator to cast to null if the key isn't set.

You can put these in a different class and with a small refactor you can make it work much nicer than doing a bunch of ifs, and it can be re-used to validate all of your api requests.